# How to Extract the string till last occurrence in Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am stuck at extracting the string till last occurrence of a char. In SQl I used to do `instr` to find the last position of the character and then used `substr` to get the string from 0 to the last position. I just want to replicate same thing in Athena.

- input: `ABC-CAD-DAB`
- Output: `ABC-CAD`

Comment: In your example, are you seeking the string until the last `-` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use: `regexp_extract(column, '(.*)-', 1)`

This does a greedy regex search for as many characters as possible before a `-`, then returns those characters.

Example:

```sql
with foo as (
  select 'ABC-CAD-DAB' as input
)

select regexp_extract(input, '(.*)-', 1)
from foo
```

This gives an output of: `ABC-CAD`

Athena uses Presto, so see documentation: [Regular Expression Functions — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html)